# Windows Universal App - MediaElement and M3U

Tags: win-universal-app, mediaelement, m3u

is it possible to open up a m3u webradio stream in a MediaElement class in Windows 10?

Sample stream would be
http://www.antenne.de/webradio/channels/top-40.m3u

Opening normal mp3 in the internet work perfect but i do not get any m3u file opened.

Kind regards
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In m3u file (playlist file), there are often links point out to the source of audio. You need to get the file, open, parse it to get urls, and supply one of them to MediaElement. Its the same when you try to streaming video.

Comment: Thanks a lot... was too simple to think about parsing the m3u file itself. With the original source it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Windows 10 version 1607, it is recommended to use the *MediaPlayer* class instead of *MediaElement* for media playback & The lightweight XAML control *MediaPlayerElement*.

Then you can use the *MediaPlaybackList* to create playlist for the MediaPlayer.

```
StorageFolder vfolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;
StorageFileQueryResult query = vfolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(Constants.QueryOptions);
var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();

MediaPlaybackList playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();

foreach (StorageFile file in files)
        {
            MediaSource source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
            playbackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));
        }

_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
_mediaPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
_mediaPlayer.Source = playbackList;
MPElement.SetMediaPlayer(_mediaPlayer);
_mediaPlayer.Play();
```

More information [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource)

Answer (score 1):

A M3U file isn't supported as it's not a media file. The playlist file format is simple and documented [well enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) that I'd recommend just parsing the M3U file and playing the individual files.

*Unfortunately, Windows 10 UWP apps do not have access to the [`Playlist`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playlists.playlist.aspx) class which would be helpful in your scenario. It's only available for Desktop applications and in a Windows 8 app.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Works now for me after parsing the file